# Catch Script Not Processing Fully

Tags: php, performance, memory-management

I have a script at https://www.domain.com/catchScript.php that a vendor POST an XML file to. Sometimes it may sit idle for hours, but sometimes it may be hit with 4+ different XML files at once and this may be repeated for hours. This script simply takes the XML data and creates new records in our database. It's a longs script - takes about 15 seconds to run each request (assume it's already optimized).

The issue I am having is catchScript.php isnt creating enough records in our database. I suspect it's timing out somehow. I currently have:

```
memory_limit at 128M
max_execution_time at 90
max_input_time at 90
```

My question is, do the values above correspond to one instance of catchScript.php or is it total? Is it wise simply set to infinite?

Comment: Did you suspect it was memory after looking at the error_log and seeing that a lack of memory caused the script to fail, or are you just taking wild guesses? *(Check the error log)*

Comment: @skrilled Got this error once "Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 38362880 bytes) in..." but it hasn't happened again, yet the processing is still incomplete.

Comment: That's definitely a memory issue then - it's always best to be 100%, thanks for checking. When a php script is run it checks php.ini for the configuration to use in that instance only. There's no such thing as a "total" where it somehow tabulates between multiple scripts if they've collectively reached a threshold. How much you can handle is based purely on the capacity of the server.